# can someone tell me if this is an efficient enough code for a login and registration system?

Tags: c++, file-handling

This code is supposed to be a login and registration system but it actually works I just want to know if there are places I can improve upon on

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void RegUser (){
    string username, password, un, pw; 
    ofstream users ("users.txt", ios::app);
    cout << "REGISTER USERNAME: " ; cin >> username;
    cout << "REGISTER PASSWORD: "; cin >> password;
        
    ifstream users_c ("users.txt");
    while (users_c >> un >> pw){
        if (username.compare(un) == 0 || password.compare(pw) == 0)
        {
            cout << "USERNAME OR PASSWORD ALREADY IN USE\n";
        }
    }   
    users_c.close();

    users << username << endl << password << endl;
    users.close();
}

int Login(string username, string password){
    string un, pw; int access = 0;
    ifstream users ("users.txt");
    while (users >> un >> pw){ 
        if (username.compare(un) == 0 && password.compare(pw) == 0)
        {
            access++;   
            break;
        }
    }
    users.close();
    return access;
}

void menu () {
    cout << "[1] TO LOGIN\n";
    cout << "[2] TO REGISTER\n";
    cout << "ENTER COMMAND: ";
}
    
main () {
        
    int cho, stop = 0, access;
    string username, password;  
        
        
    do {
        menu(); cin >> cho;
        switch (cho)
        {
        case 1: 
            cout << "ENTER USERNAME: "; cin >> username;
            cout << "ENTER PASSWORD: "; cin >> password;
            access = Login(username, password);
            if (access == 1){
                cout << "ACCESS GRANTED\n"; stop += 1;
            }
            else {
                cout << "LOGIN ERROR\n";
            }
        break;
        case 2:
            RegUser();
        break;
        }
    } while (stop != 1);




    cout << "MAIN PROGRAM PLACEHOLDER\n";
    getch();
}
```

How it works is the user will choose whether they want to login or register. Once they pick one they will be asked to enter their username or register the username they want.

The `RegUser()` function first asks for the username and password they want to use and then open the "users.txt" file to check whether the username or password already exists. if it exists it will not register and they will be brought back to the main menu which is the `menu()` function.

The `Login()` function has two arguments which are the username and password entered by the user. Once the user had entered their username and password, it will read the file and check if it resembles any of the username and password already registered in the "users.txt" file.

P.S. there are some #include commands that was not even used for the whole login and registration part but please don't mind that I just left it there because I would be using them in the future.

thank you to anyone who will reply! I'm just starting to learn c++ and want to avoid rookie mistakes.

Comment: You should ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh ok thanks I'd do that